# Can I convert my dozens of laptop adapters into universal ones by using RJ-11 or RJ-45 connections?

Tags: power-supply, rj45

I have accumulated dozens of laptop (and other) power bricks over the years. Some of them belong to a corresponding laptop or device, others just haven't been thrown away yet.

I'm trying to make them *all* useful and had an idea which I *think* will work, but wanted to see if people who know more about this can tell me if it's feasible or not.

I'm thinking of cutting the wire between block and tip and then connecting an RJ-11 or RJ-45 male on one end, female on the other.

I hope this would allow me to mix-and-match for any given situation.

Would this work? Are there heat or voltage or any other considerations that would make this not feasible? Or, is there an already-existing option that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Universal power supplies with 2 pin adapter plugs are already common.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't want to buy *more* adapters. I have literally over 30 laptop adapters already. What I want to do is make the ones that I have more useful. I'd love to figure out a way to modularize what I have so that I can use any tip with any brick.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: not like that.

Long answer: RJ11/RJ45 (aka 8p8c) connectors aren't made for delivering power.  PoE is a bit of a kludge that uses higher voltages to reduce the current to what can go through a jack and the cable, maybe an amp or two through your garden-variety connectors.  If you want an easy higher-power connection, use a barrel connector.  Bonus: it will be easier to hook up to the ~16AWG coax cable that comes out of most power bricks (that's another thing, most of the 8p8c connectors top out at the 24-22AWG range).

The thing you have to watch with the bricks is that some of them have some proprietary signalling between them and the device being powered to ensure that they're compatible.  I suspect that half of this is legitimately to prevent someone from using a cut-rate brick they got off of who knows where and damaging something.  I suspect the other half is so that Dell or whoever can charge you an arm and a leg for a replacement.

Comment: so, barrel connectors come in male and female versions? I'm in France, so trying to find the correct translation so I can look it up.

Comment: Yes, you will need a matching pair and you will have to match the barrel inner diameter and outer diameter.  5.5mm outer and 2.1mm inner is a common combination I believe.  There are female versions that mount in a panel or can be attached directly to a cable.  Virtually all of the male versions attach to a cable.

Comment: about the proprietary signaling....how do the universal laptop adapters deal with that issue?

Comment: They don't.  The universal adapters won't work with a device that checks for GENUINE DELL(TM) parts or they might but the device might charge at the slowest rate.  On one hand this kind of makes sense because you don't want someone trying to use a 65W power adapter on a monster gaming laptop and burning it up, but for a manufacturer who can prevent you from using third-party adapters, I'm sure the temptation to bump up the price a bit is just too much to bear.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1829434.pdf) 2.1mm x 5.5mm plug is the type of connector to use. In fact, you'll find this type on many laptops, usually the older ones. It's intended to be used for the modest voltage, modest current DC power output required by laptops. Centre pin positive will make it compatible with laptops, most other things, but not guitar effects pedals (ask my son how I know!)

Using a data connector for several amps is a bad idea. The pins are unlikely to be rated for it, and what happens when (inevitably) you plug the wrong things together. Use a power plug for power.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, the first thing I've learned and I'm starting to internalize is the distinction between "data connectors" and "power connectors". That's good vocabulary to know. To make this simpler, it seems I should get a bunch of these plugs, in male/female pairs. Then, I can cut the cable I have, put male on one side, female on the other. If I do this with all my bricks/tips, that should do it, right?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva It's what I've done with mine!

Comment: Very cool. I've just ordered a set of 10 pair male/female. Arrives tomorrow. Fingers crossed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question is can you, but rather, should you, and frankly that is not a good idea for many reasons.

First of all, using an existing connector for something else than it is normally used for will usually end up badly when you or someone else accidentally plugs that into your laptop, router or house phone/network wiring with damaging consequences.

You must use connectors that are rated for the voltages and currents you want to use, and these connectors are not meant for power delivery at such high currents available from laptop power supplies.

Besides laptops and their power supplies usually use a third wire for communicating how much current is available, and different brands all have their custom way for negotiating that, most likely they are not compatible and something can get damaged when wrong power supply type is connected to wrong type of laptop.

Comment: Questions in the form of "can i....?" are quite frequently "should i.....?" or that aspect is either implied or explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

- Of course there are voltage considerations and these will be specified on the label on the PSU.
- RJ11 and RJ-45 are poor choices for a power connector due to the high currents and the possibility of connection to a telephone or Ethernet device.
- Many power supplies have a third wire that is used to communicate with the laptop for power negotiation. If this is not used the PSU might not give the rated output - although it's usually the laptop is affected by the missing connection rather than the power supply.

Use a better connector that won't create confusion.

Comment: "voltage considerations" yes, I know that I have to match the PSU to the device, but I'm wondering about the connectors, what limits/restrictions would they have, if any? "possibility of connection to telephone or ethernet device" This is strictly for me, so there is no risk. "use a better connector...." such as...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a universal connector for power, use what is common in PC towers,  the “Molex” 4 pin HDD connectors.  19.5V is the most common std now for laptops.

Comment: Would the molex 4 be something that I could safely and conveniently use externally? What is most common is not really germane, because I have chargers that range from 20 to 12 (some smaller laptops like Asus eeePC). My goal is to keep the adapters I have, but be able to swap out the tips at will.